# Scope for progressive web applications with a dynamic URL

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a web application which has a changing URL on the main site (because it contains a geographic map). The URL looks like:

```
myurl.org/47.34656/8.2345356/12
```

All three parameters are variable. I want this variable URL part of my PWA scope. How can I configure my *manifest.json* file to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use the base URL, i.e. `myurl.org` as the scope for your PWA. [MDN documentation is here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope#:%7E:text=is%20a%20relative%20URL%2C%20the%20base%20URL%20will%20be%20the%20URL%20of%20the%20manifest.).